# GitHub Action ignoring Docker Containers Entrypoint

Tags: docker

I am working on a Flask application and setting up a GitHub pipeline. My Docker file has an entry point that runs a couple of commands to upgrade DB and start gunicorn.

This works perfectly fine while running locally but while deploying through GitHub action it just ignores the entry point and does not run those commands.

Hare is my Docker file -

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /opt/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x /opt/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /opt/app/
RUN chmod +x /opt/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Docker entry point content

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "*********Upgrading database************"
flask db upgrade
echo "**************Statring gunicorn server***************"
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
echo "************* started gunicorn server****************"
```

Here is my GitHub action -

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build_and_push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout files
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
  
  deploy:
    needs: build_and_push
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout files
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
    - name: Deploy to Digital Ocean droplet via SSH action
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
         
    - name: Start containers
      run: docker-compose up -d --build
      
    - name: Check running containers
      run: docker ps
```

I am very new to Dockerfiles, writing shell commands, and GitHub Actions, so please suggest if there is an any better approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ENTRYPOINT` use `CMD` inside your dockerfile. Because `Entrypoint` can override but `CMD` can not override.

Comment: Thanks for your reply YJR. After adding logs in GitHub action I can see now that my entry point is working fine and all containers are running. But when I ssh into the system and do a docker ps, I do not see any containers. So the app is also not working. Any idea? Thanks